# Select a block of lines from a text file

Tags: c#, file, parsing

I have a file with following lines

01/11/2009 23:23:23 ddd ttt, XYZ says hello

```
contains a paragraph of text which is not relevant
```

01/11/2009 23:23:23 ddd ttt, XYZ says morning

01/12/2009 21:21:21 ddd ttt, XYZ says hi how r u

how are things at your end

Can you cal me back?

```
contains a paragraph of text which is not relevant
```

01/12/2009 21:21:21 ddd ttt, XYZ says hi how r u

Here is my problem,
I am reading only those lines that contains Date, time and Keyword "Says" using StreamReader class. In doing so all the chat records which are of 1 line are extracted but the ones which has more than 1 line are getting truncated.
Eg: 01/12/2009 21:21:21 ddd ttt, XYZ says hi how r u is getting extracted but the sentences

```
how are things at your end
Can you cal me back?
```

are getting truncated. 
Can anyone please tell me how i can extract all the details of chat record without any truncation.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (File line = sr.readline())
    {
        if(line.contains("/") && line.contains(":") && line.contains("Says")
        {
            output the line to another file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very hard to deduce where problem in your code might be. Because you haven't shown your code at all.

Comment: How can you know what lines are part of the conversation and what lines are part of the irrelevant paragraph?

Comment: Hi Andy, Added the code

Comment: Hi Emile, usually it is followed by another chat record.So in my case we can assume that

Comment: 01/12/2009 21:21:21 ddd ttt, XYZ says hi how r u

how are things at your end

Can you cal me back? is followed by 01/11/2009 23:23:23 ddd ttt, XYZ says hello

Comment: Have you tried to use RegEx to decide whether string correspond to you requirements? Try to test it on http://www.regexr.com/.

Comment: You cannot treat lines individually. Try to parse the entire content as a single string by detecting the timestamp after a line break and then split the content into tokens between those time stamps.

Comment: Hi helb, this is exactly what i am looking at.I am not able to iterate through lines and detect timestamp as i am not sure how to maintain the offset of lines. Can you please provide any code for this

Comment: This is an artificial problem, induced by you using strings to store data.  Use classes instead.  Strings are for humans, classes are for computers.  Don't turn a class into a string until the last possible moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following:

- Read the file line-by-line
- Detect the time stamp art the beginnig of the line and create a new
  token.
- If no time stamp was found, append the line to the previous token.

The result is a list of strings, each containing one conversation token.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tokens = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("C:\\temp\\test.txt"))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d"))
                {
                    tokens.Add(line);
                }
                else if(tokens.Count > 0)
                {
                    tokens[tokens.Count - 1] += "\r\n" + line;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Helb. appreciate your efforts. I would verify this as soon as i reach college tomorrow in the morning and let you knw.

Comment: @sachidanandgowda If you feel that your question was answered, you should mark an answer as accepted (click the checkmark). Then, other user can see that this question was answered and no further answers are expected by you.

Comment: Done :) Thanks once again